# libgdx textField границы для текста

Tags: java, libgdx

Как можно установить границы для текста? Откуда будет начинаться текста и до куда? Текст пересекает рамку, которая поставлена как задний фон

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте: textfield.getStyle().background.setLeftWidth() - отступ слева от background, setRightWidth() - отступ справа, setBottomHeight() и setTopHeight() - снизу и сверху соответственно.

Comment: Но это же координаты и размер textField, если я их изменю, то изменится вместе с ними и background(рамка)

Comment: Вам ведь нужно, чтоб текст не выходил за рамку?  вместо width поставьте ramka.getWidth(), ramka..getHeight()

Comment: Я не правильно понял вопрос, попробуйте: 
   textfield.getStyle().background.setLeftWidth() - отступ слева от background, setRightWidth() - отступ справа, setBottomHeight() и setTopHeight() - снизу и сверху соответственно.